# How to stop/convert TLF textfield used in flash files when you have list to search?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, textfield, tlf

My designer provides me lots of MovieClips containing buttons and its states and most of them contain a TLF TextField.

Now I do not want to check each MovieClip where a TLF TextField is used.

Can I know exactly in which MovieClips and buttons a TLF TextFields has been used so that I can convert them to a classic TextField, or any method to convert all TLF TextFields to classic automatically by the compiler itself?

I tried deleting the TLF library from publish settings: it starts giving me an error, but still not pointing me to where TLF TextFields are being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change publishing settings to Flash Player 9.  TLF wasn't around then, so the IDE will automatically convert them to classic text.  Note, this DOES change the visual appearance of the text, AND it may have other effects on your FLA.

Comment: This saved my day.. I had this weird "IDS_CONSOLE_PREFIX_WARNINGIDS_CONSOLE_POLICY_BAD_SECURE_ATTR" error in an actionscript mobile app project. What I did was change publish setting to flash player 9 and thus convert ALL tlf text to classic, then I set it back to what it was (in my case flash player 11.2) and then re exported the swf with no TextLayout-blabla.swc file being created.. Ever since my error was gone, thank you.